# Receiving the error "Cannot do natural order without a primary key" while trying to download some WFS layers with ogr2ogr

Tags: wfs, ogr2ogr

I want to automate getting some public WFS data with `ogr2ogr`. When I check the data on QGIS the data looks perfectly fine:

[image]

On QGIS, I can get all data with the WFS service with no problems and I can generate Shapefile, GeoJSON, or SpatiaLite files from it.

My problem started when I tried to download these same layers with `ogr2ogr`, even though most of them worked fine and I managed to download Shapefile, GeoJSON, and SpatiaLite files from there with `ogr2ogr`, some of the files are giving me an error when I try to download them. The command that I'm using is the following:

```bsh
ogr2ogr -f GEOJSON output.json WFS:"http://wfs.geosampa.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/geoserver/geoportal/wfs" "torre_alta_tensao" -nln "layer_name"
```

I receive the following error doing that:

```
ERROR 1: Error returned by server : <ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1 http://wfs.geosampa.prefeitura.sp.gov.br:80/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.1.0/owsAll.xsd">
  <ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode">
    <ows:ExceptionText>java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException
java.io.IOException
null
Cannot do natural order without a primary key</ows:ExceptionText>
  </ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>

ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed
translation of layer geoportal:torre_alta_tensao (use -skipfailures to skip errors
```

Using the `-skipfailures` as the following:

```bsh
ogr2ogr -f GEOJSON output.json WFS:"http://wfs.geosampa.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/geoserver/geoportal/wfs" "torre_alta_tensao" -nln "layer_name" -skipfailures
```

I receive the error:

```
ERROR 1: Error returned by server : <ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1 http://wfs.geosampa.prefeitura.sp.gov.br:80/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.1.0/owsAll.xsd">
  <ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode">
    <ows:ExceptionText>java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException
java.io.IOException
null
Cannot do natural order without a primary key</ows:ExceptionText>
  </ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

I thought it could be a problem with their server since some files from there can be downloaded with no problems. But since I realized that on QGIS it works fine I'm considering it could be a problem with `ogr2ogr`. I've tried to download it as Shapefile,  GeoJSON, and SpatiaLite using `ogr2ogr` but all of them returned this error for this specific file. Is there any extra `ogr2ogr` parameter I can use to download this WFS file? Why does it work on QGIS while it doesn't work with `ogr2ogr`?

Comment: I would guess that Ogr2ogr is trying to page the results which doesn't work for tables without a primary key or other sort key. Try adding an order by to the request to confirm

Comment: @IanTurton When you say to addan order do you mean using the `-sql` option with an `order by`? I'm checking the ogr2ogr [documentation page](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html) and I've seen also an `-order` parameter. But when I try to use them I still receive the same errors. I'm not sure if I'm using them wrongly though.

Comment: @IanTurton Actually, it does work putting an order. The command `ogr2ogr -f GEOJSON output.json WFS:"http://wfs.geosampa.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/geoserver/geoportal/wfs" "torre_alta_tensao" -sql "select * from torre_alta_tensao order by cd_identificador_alta_tensao"` worked fine. The only problem with that is that I had to manually check the existence of the column `cd_identificador_alta_tensao` and figure out that it was a unique key. Different WFS files have different column names. So I'd have to find a way of identifying these unique key columns automatically.